# What Can i do to map my elements and add them for calculating max square sum?

Tags: python, matrix

I can't find the python solution to this problem. Given a square array of size N x N where each cell is to be filled with a number between a range (9,-9). A subsquare of size k is any set of k contiguous columns and k contiguous rows. For any subsquare, the sum of elements in its cells is called a sub-square sum. here I want to find maximum sum square which can be explained by this example below.

Constraints
N <= 1000

**Example**

**Input**
     4

```
 2 -8 4 -6
 7 1 -5 3
 -9 7 6 5
 8 3 2 -4
```

**Output**
20

**Explanation**
The 2 by 2 square sums are

```
2 -8 -4
6  9  9
9 18  9
```

The 3 by 3 square sums are

```
 5  7
20 18
```

And the 4 by 4 square sum is 16. Hence the maximum sub square sum is 20

I tried it out using array slicing and mapping the elements but I am quite new to python so I am unable to apply for it. An approach is required on how to solve this problem and from where to start.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: The 2 by 2 square sums are 2 -8 -4
6  9  9
9 18  9, is not this 3 by 3?

Comment: Can you format your answer again? So many typo I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

```
m = [
    [2, -8, 4, -6],
    [7, 1, -5, 3],
    [-9, 7, 6, 5],
    [8, 3, 2, -4]
]
n = len(m)
def square_sum(s):
    return [[sum(sum(r[j:j + s]) for r in m[i:i + s]) for j in range(n - s + 1)] for i in range(n - s + 1)]
print(square_sum(2))
print(square_sum(3))
print(square_sum(4))
```

This outputs:

```
[[2, -8, -4], [6, 9, 9], [9, 18, 9]]
[[5, 7], [20, 18]]
[[16]]
```